# How to Push data res from api to arrayToDataTable google Chart

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, google-visualization

```
var nullArr = [null, 0, 0, 0, 0];
var chartData = [];

for (var i = 0; i < resData.length; i++) {
       var ownArr = [];
       var grArr = [];

       grArr.push(resData[i].Title, resData[i].GrValue1, resData[i].GrValue2, 0, 0);

       ownArr.push(resData[i].Title, 0, 0, 
       resData[i].OwnValue1,resData[i].OwnValue2);
       chartData.push(grArr, ownArr, nullArr);
    }
}

var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
   ['Year', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B'],
   ['2012', 900, 390, null, null],
   ['2012', null, null, 100, 500],
   ['', null, null, null, null],
   ['2013', 1170, 440, null, null],
   ['2013', null, null, 200, 210],
   ['', null, null, null, null],
   ['2014', 1170, 440, null, null],
   ['2014', null, null, 200, 210],
]);
```

How i can push data to `arrayToTable`? my array is not correct. what happen with my data.

I want to draw chart like this: [tpcg.io/NjLnTv](http://tpcg.io/NjLnTv)

Comment: where is `arrayToTable`?

Comment: sample for resData please

Comment: http://tpcg.io/NjLnTv

Comment: http://tpcg.io/NjLnTv
I want to draw chart like this. But i don't know to add data